# Handling Type Changes with auto in C++

Tags: c++, reference, return-type, auto

A return type changed from `const Bar& getBar()` to `const Bar getBar()`.

If i use:
`const auto& bar = getBar();`

and the return type changes. I have a reference on a temporary object.

If i use:
`const auto bar = getBar();`

i always make a copy of `Bar`.

What is The best practice for this problem?

```c++
class Bar {
public:
    Bar() = default;
    Bar(const Bar&) = default;
    Bar(Bar&&) = delete;
    Bar& operator=(const Bar&) = delete;
    Bar& operator=(const Bar&&) = delete;

    void setValue(int i);
    int value() const;

private:
    int m_i = 0;
};

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(Bar& bar) : m_bar(bar) {}
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo(Foo&&) = delete;
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&&) = delete;

    const Bar& giveMeBar();

private:
    Bar& m_bar;
};

int main() {

    auto bar = std::make_unique<Bar>();
    auto foo = std::make_unique<Foo>(*bar.get());

    const auto& barFromFoo = foo->giveMeBar();
    bar->setValue(2);

    std::cout << "original bar: " << bar->value() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "bar from foo: " << barFromFoo.value() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: No, you will not have a reference to a temporary object, as in an object that gets immediately destroyed. You will be surprised to learn that you'll get a reference to a "somewhat" temporary object, which will exist until its enclosing scope ends. As far as the code in its scope goes it will be as permanent as the terra firma itself.

Comment: There's no `getBar()` in the shown code.

Comment: why do you think `auto` is relevant? `const Bar& barFromFoo = foo->giveMeBar();` vs `Bar barFromFoo = foo->giveMeBar();` is exactly same story

Comment: `auto` is just the type inference.  It's **not** duck typing, it is strong typing (via inferred type).  You'd want `auto const&` to get a const-reference, or `auto&` to get a reference, or `auto&&` to get a reference-or-const-reference as appropriate.  Or just `auto` to get a separate copy.  Or `auto const` to get a separate copy, that is const.

Comment: *What is the best practice for this problem?*  My coworkers who know a lot about this stuff say to strongly prefer **value** semantics.  Return by value.  Pass by value.  Bias in favor of immutable object APIs, rather than mutable object APIs.

Comment: Best practice is to know if you want an alias or copy and type auto& or auto depending on that.  And other best practice is when the interface of something that you used changed then you maintain your code to fit with the changes.

Comment: I wrote an answer, but actually I am not entirely sure what you refer to as "problem". Do you think there is something wrong with the current codes output? Or with the output of the code after you made the change of the return type?

Comment: Unrelated, but `const` on a by-value return type is unlikely to be useful. The only thing that it does is to prevent writing something like `getBar()->setValue(1)`. If the return value is stored in a variable, then the `const` has no relevance at all and only the `const` of the variable matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is actually "best practice" is opinion based. I will only try to explain why your premise isn't sound so you can make up your opinion on what is a good practice yourself and/or can judge some guideline on the matter.

> If i use: `const auto& bar = getBar();`
> and the return type changes. I have a reference on a temporary object.

The lifetime of the temporary is extended and bound to the constant reference. There is no problem. If you want to avoid an unnecessary copy then don't make a copy. In the shown code you can replace `const Bar& giveMeBar();` with `const Bar giveMeBar();` without any issues.

For illustration consider this example:

```
#include <iostream>


struct foo {
    ~foo(){ std::cout << "yes. I leave now. Bye\n";}
};

foo bar() { return foo{};}

int main() {
    const foo& f = bar();
    std::cout << "are you still there?\n";    
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/PqfK5Mo8c):

```
are you still there?
yes. I leave now. Bye
```

PS: `auto` does not change anything about that. The following are pairwise equivalent:

```
const auto& barFromFoo = foo->giveMeBar();   
const Bar& barFromFoo = foo->giveMeBar();   // same

// and
const auto barFromFoo = foo->giveMeBar();
const Bar barFromFoo = foo->giveMeBar();   // same
```